# How can Visual Studio single step debug an ASP.NET web app on IIS when a user from the Internet opens the web page?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I want to do single step debugging when an Internet user opens my ASP.NET web app, which is running on IIS 10 on Windows Server 2019.  I want to initiate single step debug with a breakpoint.

( I tried following the instructions "Debug ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core apps in Visual Studio" on learn.microsoft.com but since it's from a very long time ago (9/20/2018) it is too out of date:  it specifies "the Properties pane, under Servers" which doesn't exist in my Visual Studio 2019 Pro. )

How wonderful it would be to do step by step debugging of an actual external Internet user initiated session!

Comment: ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core apps are different, but you can always attach to the right process (w3wp.exe, or dotnet.exe, or something else) to debug, no matter where the traffic comes from. Visual Studio remote debugger is commonly used (even in Microsoft Azure App Service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to debug iis project using visual studio you could follow the below steps:

1. open iis manager browse your site.
2. Launch Visual Studio as Administrator mode and select your iis site folder.
3. go to debug and select attach to process.

[image]

4. In Attach to a Process dialog box, check the option Show processes from all users. 
   Search for the process w3wp.exe, and click on the Attach button.

you could also check your process id in iis worker process.

[image]

[image]

5. Accept the warning messages. That’s is you are done. Visual Studio is now attached to IIS for debugging.

[image]

Comment: This worked.  I am able to step.  But sometimes when I single steps, it goes to another line.

Comment: It works!  But why does it alternate between two different Worker Threads each stepping through page_init()  ?